# Add child or remove item by path from tree like array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have nested array of objects like

```
let treeArr =
{
  name: "Top Level", id:'a12',
  children: [
    {
      name: "Level 2: A", id:'a',
      children: [
        { name: "Daughter of A", id: 'a',
          children: [
            { name: "Another Sub0 Issuer", id: '504' },
            { name: "Another Sub1 Issuer", id: '109' },
            { name: "Another Sub2 Issuer", id: '209' },
          ]  
      }, 
      { name: "Daughter of A", id: '165' },
      ]
    }, 
    {
      name: "ABC Co LLC", id:'1234',
      children: [
          { name: "Daughter of A", id: 'a' }, 
          { name: "Daughter of A", id: 'x' },
          { name: "Daughter of Y", id: 'a',
            children:[
              { name: "Another Suba Issuer", id: '219' },
              { name: "Another Subb Issuer", id: '409',
                children:[
                  { name: "Another 4th Issuer", id: '200' }, 
                  { name: "Another 4th Issuer", id: '300' },
                  { name: "Another 4th Issuer", id: '400' }, 
                ]
              },
              { name: "Another Suba Issuer", id: '479' },
            ]
          }
        ] 
    }
  ] 
}

function findIndexNested(data, id) {
    if (data.id === id) return [];
    let result;
    const i = (data.children || []).findIndex(child => {
        return result = findIndexNested(child, id)
    });
    if (result) return [i, ...result];
}

function findByPath(data, path) {
    for (let i of path) data = data.children[i]; 
    return data
}
```

I need to delete or add children to certain children items to/from treeArr,
my finder method returns index of searched item, for example: [0, 2, 0, 1]
first children of third children of first ...

so i need to generate this as code dynamically instead hardcoded

my current ugly solution is looks like below, path returns from findIndexNested(.,.)

```
treeArr.children[path[0]].children[path[1]].children[path[2]].children[path[3]]
```

how can I add child or remove found item from treeArr ?

Comment: Why not alter your finder method to also return the parent of said item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removebyPath(obj, path, i, len ) {
    if(len===i+1){  delete obj.children[path[i]]; return;}
    removebyPath(obj.children[path[i]],path, i+1, len );  
}

let path = findIndexNested(obj, '219' );
removebyPath(obj, path, 0, path.length);

console.log('result:', obj );
```

removebyPath method removes item from passed path